# Approximaion with uniform mixture density

Tags: uniform-distribution, mixture-distribution, infinite-mixture-model

Assume that a RV is drawn from a distribution with PDF $f(x)$. I would like to approximate this distribution as a mixture of infinitely many uniform distributions. Without loss of generality, assume that I select intervals with the same length, such as $[a,b]$. The density function of that truncated distribution is then going to be, $$f_{a,b}(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{F(b)−F(a)}.I(x\in[a,b]),$$
where $F(x)$ is CDF. My approximation to $f_{a,b}(x)$ is, $$f_{a,b}(x) \approx \dfrac{1}{b-a}.I(x\in[a,b])$$
As $b-a\to 0$, $\sum f_{a,b}(x)\times Prob(x\in[a,b])\to f(x)$. I think this is simply the idea behind the infinite discrete sums (integral). I wondered if any theorems are stating this fact. (assuming this is true).

A simple illustration:

[image]

EDIT:

- @Xi'an: How can I show (weak) distance measure is converging to zero (or gets smaller)? Kullback-Leibler seems relevant. I am looking into it.
- @whuber: I try to justify stratification is a better way to approximate a full sample distribution. For example, I find sample clusters and estimate a multivariate normal distribution for each. It should work better than estimating normal distribution for the entire sample.
- @jbowman: Sorry for the ambiguity in my response to @whuber. I did not mean the conventional way of estimating the gaussian mixture densities. I would like to define clusters (e.g., [a,b] intervals), then estimate distributions within these intervals. I asked specifically for uniform distribution, but separate MVN distributions can be estimated as well.

Comment: What is the question? Convergence will occur for some (weak) distance measure and not for others (like Kullback-Leibler).

Comment: Selecting intervals of the same length does entail a loss of generality, as we know from comparing various types of integrals -- Riemann, Lebesgue, Kurweil-Henstock, Denjoy, *etc* (none of which are "infinite discrete sums," btw). Regardless, the answer depends on the specific nature of the pdf (*e.g.,* continuous or not) and, in many cases, you can approximate the pdf arbitrarily closely.  This is all a matter of the mathematics of integration: do you have some statistical application in mind?

Comment: I don't see what the Uniform distribution has to do with your response to @whuber's comment - there you are explicitly referring to a finite mixture of Normals as part of an estimation procedure, which is a very different thing indeed than proving that you can approximate a Gaussian arbitrarily well with an infinite mixture of Uniforms.